# Converting .json to .shp file in R

Tags: r, geojson

Is there any way we can convert .Json file to .SHP file using R program? I am new to R just learning new stuff around. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean how to convert a *GeoJSON* to a SHP file?

Comment: yes!! sir......

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sf` package for this like

```
library(sf)

#Read the Json file
d = read_sf("path with Json file name")

#Write it as shape file
st_write(d, "my_shapefile.shp")
```

Comment: let me try it out .